# Isolate URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters

I'm trying to get the url parameter(device) and call it out in the body. the code below works great except it'll come out as iPhone+4s*. Is there any way to remove the + and * and just have it say iPhone 4s?

url - http://mydomain.com/click.php?device=[[device_name]]

```
<script>
function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1] || ''
);
}
</script>


<body>
<script>document.write(getURLParameter('device'))</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you want the end result to be?  And, why is the + and * there in the first place?   A space should be represented as a %20 and apparently the person creating the URL thought the * was part of the name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just replace all `& + =` because they aren't going to decode as they are allowed characters in url-encoding.

```
uri = decodeURIComponent(uri);
uri = uri.replace(/\+/g, '-');
```